# Regex: Exclude character in a match

Tags: regex

Given the following characters `0100003949753>3132471430009343+ 010001628>` I would like to select everything between `>` and `+` but I dont want to include the `>` and `+`.

This pattern `>.*\+` results in `>3132471430009343+`. Can someone tell me how to exclude the two characters in order to get `3132471430009343`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookbehind or `\k`,

```
(?<=>)[^+]*(?=\+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tC7dN0/3)

OR

```
>\K[^+]*(?=\+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tC7dN0/4)

OR

Use capturing groups,

```
>([^+]*)(?=\+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tC7dN0/5)

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use capturing group:

```
>(.*)\+
```

to match selected part. **[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nE5kC5/1)**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the program which you using, but look for [positive look behind/ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).